# Line drawing characters not recognized on remote SUSE PC

Tags: linux, suse, urxvt, terminal-emulator

I'm using - remotely - a machine with SUSE installed. SUSE uses, by default, `minterm` as the terminal emulator, which doesn't seem to work well with `terminfo` over an SSH link.

I'd like to use rxvt-unicode as the terminal emulator, but for some reason, this doesn't seem to work. At least the line-drawing characters from Midnight Commander are not appearing correctly (replaced by letters).

I checked that the rxvt-unicode terminfo were correctly installed on the remote machine. I've done this on several machines without problems, just never with a SUSE distro.

More info: I *can* start urxvt from the default terminal - I just don't know how to get urxvt to be the actual default terminal!

Does anyone have a suggestion here?

Comment: ASCII letters (p's and q's) would be the VT100 line-drawing.  (u)rxvt handles that.  Usually the place to start is with the setting for `TERM` on the remote machine.  (What is "minterm"?).

Comment: I'll add some more info to the original question. Minterm is a minimal terminal emulator used bu SUSE (apparently)

Comment: The answer seems to be `gsettings` as described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18647630/4518274).

Comment: By the way, the actual question is buried in the text: you are not looking for a solution to fixing the line-drawings, but looking for a method to change the default terminal.  The question is mistitled as well.